# How to export glTF file with ambient occlution?

Tags: blender, texture-mapping, gltf

I am using group nodes (input and output). But export in blender3.4 GLTF file.The ambient occlution file doesn't export with gltf file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHTNu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiArn.png)

This Ambient occlution texture connect to GLTF Material output (group node) node. It shows the Ambient occlution map in Three.js editor.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmaSP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apKEx.png)

I added those all nodes and ambient occlution map also then I export the model as GLTF file. Then I import the same model into the blender again those nodes are deleted automatically.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7es7s.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Taking as a reference your posted images links and node names, what worked for me was connecting the "Color" output from the "OCCLUSION" texture node directly to the "Occlusion" input from the "glTF Material Output" node, also I had a "Principled BSDF" node with many texture connections including albedo, emission, normal, roughness and metallic.

Maybe the inclusion of the roughness and metallic textures are important? I am not so sure. But when I exported the model from Blender as glTF 2.0 I chose under Format: "glTF Separate". When the export ended, it generated various textures, including a combined texture of 3 channels (RGB) with Ambient Occlusion (Red channel), Roughness (Green channel) and Metallic (Blue channel).

[Screenshot of my material nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpkk8.png)